# Game Center vs Socket Programming&Server for iPhone App?

Tags: ios, sockets, swift, real-time, game-center

I have requirement of developing an Quiz Game but real time. I have read a little about it and went through some tutorials and documentations.

I have a queries in my mind regarding making it real time and effective.

I want to ask that

**Whether I should use Game Center or Socket Programming where server is made in PHP/Asp.net or Python.**

As, the architecture which I am thinking to make is looks like as below...

Architect…..

1. Download All Categories.
2. Select Subject, or Category/topic, every category can have many subjects.
3. After selecting, you will press button, Play now, it will send query to server, that you want to play., server will choose any one who also want to play and searching for some opponent 
   After both opponents are selected, it will send data to both, means in response of previous request, a user along with data of questions will be send.
4. As every question has fixed time, fixed score, so locally it will be shown and calculated and score will be sent to server and server will also show score to both players. means another data will be send, but very small data, say one string or two.
5. As time will be over, another request will be sent and final result will be displayed.

Thanks

Proper guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this tutorial. It will clear your concepts.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4456/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server

Comment: Thanks. let me read it.